# Where to add a script that acts on the scrolling action?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, navbar

I am trying to make a `div` visibe only after a certain scroll length. 
There are already some threads here on Stackoverflow about it and so I have tried to use the suggested scripts listed in the answers, but no one of them seems to work.

So, I suppose that I don't know how to use them.

I have put this block into the `head`, surrounded by the two `script` tags:

```
function scroll_bar() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 700) {
        document.getElementById("navigation_bar").show();
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("navigation_bar").hide();
    }
}
```

And in the `body`, I have a `div` (the one that I want to make visible/hidden) with these attributes:

```
<div onload="scroll_bar();" class="container" id="navigation_bar" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1; background-color: white; height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

What is wrong over here?
(I am using Bootstrap anyway, that "container" class comes from it.)

Comment: With "it seems to not work" I mean that it doesn't react in any sense to the function, it's like it doesn't exist.

Comment: Remove Position : fixed and check

Comment: No, I want to make it fixed to the top (it is on the top, on the z-index 1) during scrolling...

Comment: move onload="scroll_bar();" to body

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an event listener to the 'scroll' event: `window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll_bar)`. Also in your handler I would use `window.pageYOffset instead` of `document.body.scrollTop`.

Comment: Uhm where exaclty have I to add the listener?

Comment: Solved. :)    I have put it into the body attributes, as...  onscroll="window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll_bar)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your `<script>` in your `<head>`, put in just before your closing body tag (`</body>`). This will make sure that content is loaded before the script and therefore your script should run correctly.

```
  <p>I'm some content!</p>

  <script>console.log('JavaScript!');</script>

</body>
```

Also, you need to make sure that your script function fires on [the body scroll event.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Are U sure it's good??

```
document.getElementById("navigation_bar").show();
```

**"document.getElementById("navigation_bar")."** is javascript.

**"show()"** is jquery.

try:

```
document.getElementById("navigation_bar").style.display = 'block'/'none'
```

or

```
$("#navigation_bar").show();
```

Comment: Oh many thanks I didn't knew that. Jquery is included anyway because I'm using Bootstrap and it is there by default...

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced your event to div.

please move your event BODY

**code**

```
<body onload="scroll_bar();" >
<div class="container" id="navigation_bar" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1; background-color: white; height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
```